# How do I change the label of my Hypothesis?

Tags: labels

For the hypothesis, I am currently coding as follows:

```
\begin{hypolist}
\item Learning Capacity Hypothesis...
\end{hypolist}
```

I want the "**title**" of my hypothesis to be "Learning Capacity Hypothesis" but it *(as well as my others)* are showing up as "**Hypothesis 1**".

How do I get rid of the **hypothesis 1** label and replace it with my own **title**?

The document type is `cupjournal`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By all means, please do tell us how you created the `hypolist` environment.